# about K-Nearest Neighbor and OpenCV in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, knn

I am wondering if there is a built-in function in OpenCV that performs KNN ?

If it exists how can I deal with it .. I searched but I didn't find any useful thing

thank

Answer (score 2):

It certainly appears to exist, if this is the right method you need:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/k_nearest_neighbors.html

This blog post shows how to use it in C:

http://www.aishack.in/2010/10/k-nearest-neighbors-in-opencv/

That should be portable to your C# wrapper.

If you're using the Emgu wrapper, heres a tutorial showing KNN in C#:

http://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/K_Nearest_Neighbors_in_CSharp

Comment: I found these links before .. but I need some direct KNN in C# .. any way .. thank you .. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to a tutorial showing KNN in C# using a wrapper.

Comment: thank you .. :) .. but I found this too .. when I build the program, a weird error appears `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Emgu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` I don't know why is that

Comment: You need to download the Emgu binary and add the assembly to your project as a reference. This page has the instructions:  http://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation